# Find and replace in excel file and then open it with Excel app

Tags: excel, vb.net, openfiledialog, find-replace

I want to do a replace inside an xls file and then open it with Excel.
I have this

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim strFileName As String

        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Apri file TimeSheet"
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "File Excel (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        If OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Length > 0 Then
            strFileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
            Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
            wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName.ToString())
            wb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Replace(".", ",")
            wb.Save()
            wb.Close()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", strFileName)
            End
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

But the process.start fails* because the file appears to be moved, even if path and filename are the same. How can I solve this at runtime (meaning without user intervenction)?

*meaning Excel app starts but can't open the file and throw an error about "can't open the file, maybe it was moved or it is unaccessible"

Comment: This code is no VBA code? Please clarify. Also *"fails"* is a completely useless error description.

Comment: Do you have `OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` in your code?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ added a clarification
it is not my app failing, it is Excel that cannot find the processed file, I'm asking a way to launch the file in strFileName directly with Excel after find/replace processing

Comment: What type is the variable `strFileName`? You used `strFileName.ToString()` before to open it, so it is obviously not a string? • And this is not VBA code! Please tell which type of code this is and where you use it?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I updated the post with full code (the entire code in my app). I'm using vb.net

Comment: Does the path in `strFileName` contain spaces? If yes you might need to enclose it in `""` try `""" & strFileName & """` instead.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ works with  """" & strFileName & """" thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced

```
Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", strFileName)
```

with

```
Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", """" & strFileName & """")
```

First failed because the filename contained a space.